# Cross Platform React Native vs NativeScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

it's just a simple question it has been more than 2h searching what to learn next ! i want something that will make me able to create a cross-platform app: web - android - ios . I've been teared up between NativeScript and react native + Reactxp.. i need your experience guys thank you !
bringing the power of web to phones.

Comment: https://academind.com/learn/flutter/react-native-vs-flutter-vs-ionic-vs-nativescript-vs-pwa/

Comment: @NarendraMongiya thank you, i guess i wasn't  they both do a  great job for mobile but my need is to have the same codebase for web and phone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you want to share the same codebase for web and phone, NativeScript is an obvious choice.The Angular and NativeScript teams teamed up to create nativescript-schematics, a schematic collection that enables you to build both web and mobile apps from a single project.

A code-sharing project is one where we keep the code for the web and mobile apps in one place. Here’s a quick diagram to show you what that looks like at a high level.

The objective is to share as much code as possible, and split the platform-specific code into separate files.

This usually means that we can share the code for:

Routes for navigation,
Services for common business logic,
and Component Class definition for common behaviour of a component
While, splitting the code for:

UI Layer (CSS and HTML) - as you need to use different user interface components in web and NativeScript-built native apps,
and NgModules - so that you can import platform-specific modules, without creating conflicts (e.g. Angular Material Design - which is web only) between web and mobile.

To create two separate templates, you just need to use a naming convention. Simply create two files:

yourcomp.component.html - the web template file,
yourcomp.component.tns.html - the NativeScript template file - it is the .tns that makes it a {N} file.

You can even migrate from your existing project, you can fine the instructions [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@nativescript/schematics)

P.S.The @nativescript/schematics package only works with @angular/cli: 6.1.0 or newer.